# How can I fix No argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter?

Tags: c#

I'm getting an error that says *There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'employee' of 'Job_Form(Program.Employee, Program.Job, Program.Job, Program.Job)*

I know that is something to do with not passing parameter however then when I pass in the parameter I get another error saying Program.Employee is type that is not valid in given context

```
namespace company
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Employee
        {
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
            public int IQ { get; set; }
            public string CurrentJob {get;set;}
        }
        public class Job
        {
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
            public string JobDescription { get; set; }
            public int IQRequired { get; set; }
            public int Salary { get; set; }
            public bool Available { get; set; }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {      
            void Create_Jobs()
            {
                Job Job1 = new Job();
                Job1.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                Job1.JobDescription = "CEO";
                Job1.IQRequired = 100;
                Job1.Salary = 100000;
                Job1.Available = false;

                Console.WriteLine("Jobs Avaiable \n");
                Console.WriteLine(Job1.JobDescription + "\n IQ Required  :" + Job1.IQRequired + "\nSalary :" + Job1.Salary +"\n");                
            }
            void Create_Employee()
            {
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Name");
                employee.Name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Age");
                employee.Age = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Age");
                employee.CurrentJob = "empty";
                Random Rnd = new Random();
                employee.IQ = Rnd.Next();
            }
            void Job_Form(Employee employee,Job Job1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("what job Would you like:");

                if (Console.ReadLine() == "1" && (employee.IQ >= 50) && (Job1.Available == true))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have been Hired");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry we werent able to take you on ");
                }
            }
            Create_Jobs();
            Create_Employee();
            Job_Form(Employee employee, Job Job1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo?  You don't pass type information when calling a method: `Job_Form(employee, Job1);`  The method already knows what types it expects, you just provide it parameters of that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't specify argument type in method call.

```
Job_Form(employee, Job1);
```

Edit:

Another issue as mentioned in comments.

Modify the two local functions to the following:

```
            // Change return type from void to Job
            Job Create_Jobs()
            {
                Job Job1 = new Job();
                Job1.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                Job1.JobDescription = "CEO";
                Job1.IQRequired = 100;
                Job1.Salary = 100000;
                Job1.Available = false;

                Console.WriteLine("Jobs Avaiable \n");
                Console.WriteLine(Job1.JobDescription + "\n IQ Required  :" + Job1.IQRequired + "\nSalary :" + Job1.Salary +"\n");
               
               // return created object        
               return Job1;        
            }

            // Change return type from void to Employee
            Employee Create_Employee()
            {
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Name");
                employee.Name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Age");
                employee.Age = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Age");
                employee.CurrentJob = "empty";
                Random Rnd = new Random();
                employee.IQ = Rnd.Next();

                // return created object
                return employee;
            }
```

Since `Job1` and `employee` is defined in a different scope, the compiler won't know where they come from, therefore an error.

Now that the method returns the created object, you can use it in the `Main` method:

```
var Job1 = Create_Jobs();
var employee = Create_Employee();
Job_Form(employee, Job1);
```

Comment: Thank you but then it says The name employee dosent exist in the current context and The name Job1dosent exist in the current context

Comment: You're using parameters defined in local function, so your code still won't work.
Either move `employee` and `Job1` to the same scope as your main method or make them return the created value.

Comment: thank you I'm new to coding as you can tell how would I make it work without moving employee would it be public void Create_Employee()

Comment: Because those variables are local to the Create methods. Let those methods return what they have created. `Employee Create_Employee() { ...; return employee; }` and then call it like this: `Employee employee = Create_Employee();`

Comment: @Coder175 I've updated my answer, take a look if you still have any questions

Comment: Thank you how would i add another job as then the parameter referencing would mess up exmaple of new job "Job job2 = new Job();
                job2.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                job2.JobDescription = "manager";
                job2.IQRequired = 175;
                job2.Salary = 75000;
                job2.Available = true;"

Comment: The variable's name in`Create_Jobs` doesn't matter, you can create another job like this:`var job2 = Create_Jobs()`. I suggest you to take a look at [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/understanding-scope-and-visibility-in-c) to understand how variable scope works.